# Somewhat "combining" Tomcat and Apache

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.2

So I have a web application that runs on Tomcat, but I also have Apache running, so I can't forward Tomcat to use port 80, so now its just sitting at 8080.  Is there anyway I can configure the two of them to kinda "work together" so if I put in http://app.domain.com/ it would go to the Tomcat application?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache's [Name-Based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) configuration will allow you to accomplish this fairly easily: set up a name-based vhost for your Tomcat app and configure it to use mod_jk to talk to Tomcat.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at mod_proxy_ajp as many are moving from mod_jk to its use these days.  It has some advantages in certain situations over mod_jk.